# Optimization methods for probability distributions with respect to percentiles (for example medians)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, parameter-estimation

**This question became quite a mess because of unclarities and need to edit several times, so I made a new one [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357107/finding-parameters-for-probability-distributions-with-prescribed-position-of-per)**. Please do not answer this question but go to the updated one instead.

---

I am aware of many methods in statistics to optimize with respect to moments like mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, but which methods exist to optimize with respect to a given median $(50\%)$ or more general case $x\%$ percentile? I don't remember it being treated in any literature I have read.

---

**Edit:** Clarification. The intent was to ask about methods which estimate the parameters of parametric distributions given the position of the prescribed percentiles. For a trivial example a uniform distribution prescribed $50\%$ at $x=1$ and $100\%$ at $x=2$ would be the uniform distribution with density function constant $0.5$ on the interval $x\in [0,2]$ and $0$ everywhere else.

---

**Edit 2**

Ok I will try rephrase again. How to find the parameters for a distribution having the cumulative distribution function $F$ satisfying $F(x_k) = c_k$ for some $n$ prescribed pairs $(x_k,c_k)$, $k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ or in terms of density function $f$: $\int_{-\infty}^{x_k} f(t) dt=c_k$. Or if not solvable, to minimize the error in some suitable way. (Maybe this error minimization procedure is where efforts should be spent?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "optimize with respect to." An obvious way to
estimate the population median, sometimes denoted $\eta,$ is to find the
sample median, sometimes denoted $H.$

For many symmetrical distributions, the population mean $\mu$ is the same
as the population median $\eta.$ Then the 'best' estimator of $\eta$ from
a sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ may be the sample mean $\bar X.$ An example
is a normal distribution. The unbiased estimator of the 'center' $\mu = \eta$
with the smallest variance is $\bar X.$

> Without going into the distribution theory, here is a demonstration via simulation for
>   samples of size $n = 10$ from a normal distribution, that both $\bar X$ (`A`
>   in the R code) and $H$ are unbiased estimators of the center, but that the sample mean is a less-variable estimator of the center than is the sample median.

```
m = 10^6;  n = 10
x = rnorm(m*n, 100, 15)
DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)   # each of m rows is a normal sample of size n
A = rowMeans(DTA)         # vector of m sample means
H = apply(DTA, 1, median) # vector of m sample medians
mean(A);  mean(H)         # A and H both unbiased estimators of center
## 99.99282                 # aprx E(A) = 100
## 99.99174                 # aprx E(H) = 100
sd(A);  sd(H)             # But A has less variability than H
## 4.747664                 # aprx SD(A) = 15/sqrt(10) = 4.743416
## 5.585213                 # indicates SD(H) > SD(A)
```

However, the Laplace (double exponential) distribution is also symmetrical
and the best estimator of the center $\mu = \eta$ is the sample median $H.$

> Here is an analogous demo that for a Laplace distribution, the sample median
>   is a better estimator of the center than the sample mean. I generated a Laplace
>   random variable $X$ as $X = U - V + 100,$ where $U$ and $V$ are independent exponential distributions with rate 1. Thus $E(X) = 100.$

```
m = 10^6;  n = 10
x = rexp(m*n)-rexp(m*n)+100
DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)
A = rowMeans(DTA);  H = apply(DTA, 1, median)
mean(A);  mean(H)  # Both estimators unbiased
## 99.99987
## 99.99969
sd(A);  sd(H)      # But median H has less variability
## 0.4466381
## 0.3809883
```

Also, there are cases in which neither $\bar X$ nor $H$ is best. An example is
uniform distributions of the form $\mathsf{Unif}(0, \theta),$ for which
the center is $\mu = \eta = \theta/2.$ An unbiased estimator of $\theta$ is
$\hat \theta = \frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)} = \max X_i.$ Then the best estimator
of the center is $\hat \theta/2.$

There are even some useful symmetrical distributions that do not have 
a population mean $\mu,$ and so one may use the median $\eta$ as the center
and try to estimate it by $H$. An example is Student's t distribution with
one degree of freedom.

Finally, there are distributions in which $\mu \ne \eta,$ such as the
family of gamma distributions, including the exponential. For these, it may
be best to use $\bar X$ to estimate $\mu,$ find the relationship between
$\mu$ and $\eta,$ and modify the estimator of $\mu$ to get an estimator
of $\eta.$

In a mathematical statistics course one important topic of discussion is methods 
of finding optimal estimators for various parameters. This is not the place
for a full discussion. If you can say something about your background in
statistics and the situation(s) in which you want to estimate population
medians and quantiles, perhaps I or someone else can give an answer targeted
on your primary interests.

Comment: The intent was that if it is a parametric distribution, to find the parameters which get the prescribed percentiles or minimize the distance to them (in some sense). Estimating percentiles already having the parameters would just be numerical integration and not optimization, wouldn't it?

Comment: I added an example which hopefully clarifies what I want such an algorithm to accomplish. I have a couple of university degrees and have taken some PhD courses but it is applied math (engineering) and not very pure.

Comment: Ok I will try rephrase again. How to find the parameters for a distribution having the cumulative distribution function $F$ satisfying $F(x_k) = c_k$ for some prescribed pairs $x_k,c_k$ or in terms of density function $f$: $\int_{-\infty}^{x_k} f(t) dt=c_k$. Or if not solvable, to minimize the error in some suitable way. (Maybe this error minimization procedure is where efforts should be spent?)

Comment: If you have the CDF and it is integrable, integrate to get the PDF (density function), then use the PDF to find parameters. If you have only a few points on the CDF, and you know how to express them in terms of parameters, then solve the required equations. (Trivial example: if you know dist'n is normal and that 30th and 70th percentiles are 10 and 20 respectively, then you know $\mu = 15.$) If you don't know the functional connection btw quantiles and parameters, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Yes I also thought something along these lines, but many densities are difficult to integrate analytically (already the normal distr is) and even if possible we would end up with quite non-linear equations to try and solve in an equation system. Anyway thanks alot for the help. I think I should get some sleep so I can formulate better questions with examples from the start next time.

Comment: We are getting busted for chatting in Comments. I deleted a couple of my (seemingly now obsolete) Comments. I have a policy never to chat; almost always a waste of time. If you have a _specific_ distribution and application in mind, please ask that, and maybe someone can help. As it is, you have posed a potentially messy problem without enough specifics for traction. I tried to illustrate in my Answ that different parametric families pose very different difficulties of estimation.

Comment: Yes, do that if you want. The question became a mess because of all the edits, I leave a +1 for you as thanks for the help making me see what I needed to clarify and make a new clearer question where it is not so easy to misinterpret as this one.