# Finding parameters for probability distributions with prescribed position of percentiles.

Tags: probability, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

I am aware of many methods in statistics to optimize with respect to moments like mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, but which methods exist to optimize with respect to a given median $(50\%)$ or more general case $x\%$ percentile? I don't remember it being treated in any literature I have read (which includes standard probability courses up to MSc level Electrical Engineering and PhD courses signal processing).

---

In technical terms what I am interested to do: 
I am looking for an algorithm to find the parameters for a distribution having the cumulative distribution function $F$ satisfying $$F(x_k) = c_k$$ for some prescribed pairs $$(x_k,c_k) \,,\,k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$$ or in terms of the probability density function $f$: $$\int_{-\infty}^{x_k} f(t) dt=c_k$$If these are not solvable exactly, the algorithm should strive to minimize the error in some suitable way. (Maybe to develop / derive this error minimization procedure is where efforts should be spent?)

---

To give a simple example the method I am searching for if we had a uniform distribution prescribed $50\%$ at $x=1$ and $100\%$ at $x=2$ the output should be the uniform distribution with density function constant $0.5$ on the interval $x\in [0,2]$ and $0$ everywhere else.

If we are searching for a normal distribution then prescribing the $50\%$ percentile then our method should lock in our parameter $\mu$ (as median and mean are the same for the normal distributions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pairs $(x_k,c_k)$ satisfy $F(x_k)=c_k$, we can construct the rest of the cdf $F$ by linearly interpolating between those values, and by linearly extrapolating beyond the biggest and smallest until we reach 0 and 1.

E.g. if the pairs are $(0,25\%), (1,50\%), (2,100\%)$, then a reasonable choice for $F$ is
\begin{cases}
F=\ \ 0 \ \ \ \text{ if } x\in [-\infty,-1]\\
F=\frac{1+x}{4} \text{ if } x \in [-1,+1]\\
F=x/2 \text{ if } x\in [+1,+2]\\
F=\ \ 1 \ \ \text{ if } x\in [+2,+\infty]
\end{cases}
This yields a piecewise constant pdf:
\begin{cases}
f=\ \ 0 \ \ \text{ if } x\in (-\infty,-1)\\
f=1/4 \text{ if } x \in (-1,+1)\\
f=1/2 \text{ if } x\in (+1,+2)\\
f=\ \ 0 \ \ \text{ if } x\in (+2,+\infty)
\end{cases}

Alternatively we can use [monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) cubic interpolation to define the cdf, which will yield a continuous pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is useful, but I was thinking:

The p.d.f of the $k^{th}$ order statistic from a sample of size $n$ from a distribution which is uniformly distributed over $[a,b]$ is $$ f_{(k)}(x) =  n\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right){{n-1}\choose{k-1}}\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{n-k} $$ So if you take $p$ samples of size $n$ and from each sample take the $k^{th}$ ordered element, you can construct a likelihood function $$ L(a,b|x) = n^p\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)^{np}{{n-1}\choose{k-1}}^p\left(\prod_{i=1}^n{(x_i-a)}\right)^{k-1}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n{(b-x_i)}\right)^{n-k}  $$ Taking log both sides
$$ \ln{L(a,b|x)} = p\ln{n} - np\ln{(b-a)} + p\ln{{n-1}\choose{k-1}} + (k-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\ln{(x_i-a)} + (n-k)\sum_{i=1}^n\ln{(b-x_i)}  $$

Then $$ \frac{\partial \ln{L}}{\partial a} = \frac{np}{b-a}-(k-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{x_i-a}\right) $$ and $$ \frac{\partial \ln{L}}{\partial b} = -\frac{np}{b-a}+(n-k)\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{b-x_i}\right) $$ Setting those both equal to zero and adding them together you get the relation $$ \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{b-x_i}\right) = \frac{k-1}{n-k} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{x_i-a}\right)   $$ I don't know how to simplify this or even if it's possible to do so, or even if any of this is correct.

Comment: We don't have samples, we have prescribed values of the cumulative distribution function.